# Embed does not include svg properly

Tags: javascript, html, svg

The following simple HTML/SVG/javascript example works fine when open on server.

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>2. Empty Network (2)</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2"><!--
/*
* This function turns on/off various layers of the SVG picture.
* It is called when the user clicks on any of the checkboxes in
* the form below.
*
* Input Parameters:
*   checkbox     - Form object (checkbox) that was clicked on.
*   element_name - SVG element name that should be made visible/
*                  invisible.
*/
function hilite_elem (checkbox, element_name)
{
   var svgobj;
   var svgstyle;
   var svgdoc = document.network.getSVGDocument();
  // For selected element, get the elements style object, then set
  // its visibility according to the state of the checkbox.
   svgobj = svgdoc.getElementById(element_name);

   if (!checkbox.checked)
   { // Hide layer.
      svgobj.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
   }
   else
   { // Show layer.
      svgobj.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline');
   }

}
// -->
</SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#fffff4">
 <center>
 <table><tr><td>
  <EMBED SRC="2.svg" NAME="network"
   HEIGHT="401.00" WIDTH="469.00"
   TYPE="image/svg+xml"
   PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/">
 </td><td>
<FORM NAME="hilite_form">
 <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="2" WIDTH="100%">
  <TR>
   <TD><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" VALUE="" ONCLICK="hilite_elem(this,0)">1</TD> 
   </tr>
   <TD><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" VALUE="" ONCLICK="hilite_elem(this,1)">2</TD> 
 </tr>
 </TABLE>
 <SCRIPT><!--
  // Make sure all checkboxes are checked whenever the page
  // is reloaded in the browser.
    for (var i = 0;  i < document.hilite_form.elements.length;  i++)
      if (document.hilite_form.elements[i].type == 'checkbox')
        document.hilite_form.elements[i].checked = true;
  // -->
 </SCRIPT>
</FORM>
</td></tr>
 </table>
 </center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please try it from here: http://mrvar2.fdv.uni-lj.si/aa/x/2.htm

What I mean by 'works fine' is that clicking on checkboxes I can hide or show yellow or green circle. It works on Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Edge.

However if I copy the two files (2.htm and 2.svg) to my local machine it works only on Internet Explorer. The two files are available here:

http://mrvar2.fdv.uni-lj.si/aa/x/2.zip

Comment: Because browsers security model does not allow one file to access the contents of another if you run locally. Use a local web server.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Everything is clear now.